# Differentiating by Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

[image]

I don't understand why its raised to -1/2 (don't you have to subtract 1?)

Can you differentiate by chain-rule? Yes/no and why?

Comment: Upon taking the derivative, the appropriate power is $\frac 1 2 - 1 = -\frac 1 2$.

Comment: so it's not  -1/2−1=−1 (do you always use the absolute value??)

OH WAIT its -1/2 -.-

Comment: Well, $-1/2 - 1$ is *not* equal to $-1$. I'm not sure what you mean about absolute value.

Comment: i know, i just realised. that's a fail.

i kept subtracting by 1/2.. i dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt{x^2+1}=(x^2+1)^{1/2},$$
we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{(1/2)-1}(x^2+1)^\prime.$$

Comment: so in this case we apply the quotient rule, and then the chain-rule within???

Comment: Both are needed.

Comment: why do we even need to use the quotient rule?

Cant we just use the product rule?

Comment: What are you talking about? about f(x)? or about the function I wrote?

Comment: f(x) if we arrange it is as x(x^2+1)^-1/2 isnt that just using the product rule?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.